# How to design factory pattern for different types of values in one list?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, collections, factory

I need to design a data structure that holds different types of values (doubles, strings, datetimes, etc.). The list of types is dynamically created by user. Based on that list another list of values should be created.
Then this "record" of values is to be sent by WCF and stored in dynamically created db table. I'm starting with desiging this solution in c#. My current status is shown below. I'm not satisfied with my present solution, especially with factory and enums. Is there better way to do the things right?

Enum for my types:

```
public enum ValueType { Decimal, String, Boolean };
```

then interface:

```
public interface IValueType
    {
        object Data { get; }
        string ToString();
        ValueType? Type { get; }
    }
```

base class:

```
public abstract class ValueType<T> : IValueType
{
    protected T _Value;

    public ValueType(T value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return _Value; }
    }

    public ValueType? Type
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

one of implementation:

```
public class DecimalValueType : ValueType<decimal>
{
    public DecimalValueType( decimal val ) : base(val)
    {}
    public DecimalValueType(double val) : base((decimal)val)
    {}
    public DecimalValueType(int val) : base((decimal)val)
    {}
}
```

then factory:

```
public static class ValueTypeFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<ValueType, Type> dictValueType = new Dictionary<ValueType, Type>()
    {
        { ValueType.Decimal, typeof(DecimalValueType) },
        { ValueType.String, typeof(StringValueType) },
        { ValueType.Boolean, typeof(BooleansValueType) }
    };

    private static Dictionary<Type, Type> dictSimple = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
    {
        { typeof(decimal), typeof(DecimalValueType) },
        { typeof(double), typeof(DecimalValueType) },
        { typeof(int), typeof(DecimalValueType) },
        { typeof(string), typeof(StringValueType) },
        { typeof(bool), typeof(BooleansValueType) }
    };

    public static IValueType MakeByValueType(ValueType type, params object[] initValues)
    {
        IValueType retObject = null;
        if (dictValueType.ContainsKey(type) )
        {
            Type t = dictValueType[type];
            retObject = (IValueType)Activator.CreateInstance(t,initValues);
        }
        return retObject;
    }

    public static IValueType MakeByType(params object[] initValues)
    {
        IValueType retObject = null;
        if ( initValues.Length > 0 )
        {
            Type type = initValues[0].GetType();
            if (dictSimple.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                Type t = dictSimple[type];
                retObject = (IValueType)Activator.CreateInstance(t, initValues);

            }
        }
        return retObject;
    }
}
```

sample use:

```
    List<IValueType> lista = new List<IValueType>();
    lista.Add(new DecimalValueType(12));
    lista.Add(new StringValueType("Test"));
    lista.Add(new BooleansValueType(true));
    lista.Add(ValueTypeFactory.MakeByValueType(ValueType.Decimal, 10.1));
    lista.Add(ValueTypeFactory.MakeByType(5.12));
    lista.Add(ValueTypeFactory.MakeByType("Test2"));
```

I would be happy with any advice.

Comment: I get an "over-engineered" feeling out of this. Most likely you have to explain your use case (and why you are doing this in the first place) a little more. E.g., in what way is this better than a List<object> and a whitelist as HashSet<Type> on top of it?

Comment: In desktop application I'm receiving record of more then 200 realtime parameters with some time step. My goal is to make a bridge between this desktop app (written in mfc) and web application (connected to sql database). I've decided to use WCF API. Administrator of web application creates a list of parameters that he wants to have in db. So I have to make a list of that paramaters in its types - based on that create table and send a proper list of values to WCF service.

Comment: The `IValueType` interface looks useless. I would simply have a `public abstract class ValueType<T>` with a protected constructor. I would then use a factory that relies on reflection to find concrete `ValueType<T>` implementations if the client code just want types to be inferred automatically and I wouldn't implement a `MakeByValueType` operation. It's the same as `new ConcreteValueType(...)`.

Comment: I thought that the IValueType is needed tu put all derived class to one collection - that I cannot add generic version of ValueType<T> (with different T) into one collection. 
About enum - user has to have a choice to (some list of different types) choose needed parameter type. So I made a connection between choosed type and IValueType instance created by static method MakeByValueType. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution that covers the usages in your post and avoids the `ValueType` subclass noise:

```
public abstract class ValueType
{
    public enum Types { Decimal, String, Boolean };
    public abstract object Data { get; }
    public abstract Types Type { get; }
    private ValueType() {}

    protected class TypedValueType<T> : ValueType
    {
        private Types type;

        public TypedValueType(T value, Types type) : base()
        {
            this.Value  = value;
            this.type   = type;
        }

        public override object Data { get { return this.Value; } }
        public override Types Type { get { return this.type; } }
        public T Value { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Value.ToString();
        }

    }

    public static implicit operator ValueType(decimal value) { return new TypedValueType<decimal>(value, Types.Decimal); }
    public static implicit operator ValueType(double value) { return new TypedValueType<decimal>((decimal)value, Types.Decimal); }
    public static implicit operator ValueType(int value) { return new TypedValueType<decimal>((decimal)value, Types.Decimal); }
    public static implicit operator ValueType(string value) { return new TypedValueType<string>(value, Types.String); }
    public static implicit operator ValueType(bool value) { return new TypedValueType<bool>(value, Types.Boolean); }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ValueType> lista = new List<ValueType>();
        lista.Add(1);
        lista.Add("Test");
        lista.Add(true);
        lista.Add(10.1);
        lista.Add(5.12);
        lista.Add("Test2");
        foreach(var value in lista) Console.WriteLine(value.Data + " - " + value.Type.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Since it appears that you are wanting to restrict the types of values that can be contained, the nested `TypedValueType` class is marked protected and the `ValueType` constructor is marked private.  Implicit operators are used to provide the "factory" logic for producing the appropriate typed `TypeValueType` subclasses for the values that are to be casted.

Here is the output from executing this as a console app:

```
1 - Decimal
Test - String
True - Boolean
10.1 - Decimal
5.12 - Decimal
Test2 - String
```

Comment: Great solution! Very clean & elegant. Nice use of implicit operators. Thank you very much!